# Cook's distance, altering diagnostic plot in R,?

Tags: r, predictive-modeling, statistics, data

I have a linear model in R, named Q1fit. I am interested in the plot of the residuals vs leverage, with Cook's distance. When I run

plot(Q1fit, which=(5))

I get

[image]

There is no Cook's distance line visible here. Does that mean the Cook's distance goes beyond the axes, and I need to change the limits? If so, how can I do that without giving an error (as my attempts keep doing).